# Left exact functors and long exact sequences

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I wonder whether in any Abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ when we have a long exact sequence $0\to M_1\to M_2\cdots\to M_n\to 0$ and a (covariant) left exact functor $F$ we have $0\to FM_1\to FM_2\to \cdots FM_n$.

I know this is certainly true if $n=3$ (i.e. we have a short exact sequence), but what about in general, may I ask?

This question comes from Page 118 of Assem, Simson and Skowronski's book, *Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras, Volume 1*, where the authors seem to have used this supposed property in the proof of the Auslander-Reiten Formula.

Comment: If this were true and you take $M_4=0$, then it would follow that $F$ is exact.

Comment: @user218931 Oh! You are right. So the better question is why did Assem Simson and Skowronski did that in their proof. There is nothing projective there.. I need to modify the question. Thank you very much!

Comment: After having had a short look at the proof, I don't see, where they would use something like this. There is only one place, where they apply a functor to a longer-than-short exact sequence. But they do not claim, that the resulting complex is exact.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is great! It clarifies many things for me!