# Ext functor and left exact sequence?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, derived-functors, functors

We define $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R (A,B) = H^n(\operatorname{  Hom}_R(P,B))$, where $P$ is a projective resolution of A. $\operatorname{Hom}_R (-,B)$ is a left exact functor so $\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,B)$ is a left exact sequence. Does it mean $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R(A,B) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$? If no, what is the definition of left (right) exactness for long sequences? Would you please recommend a reference for studying more about left (right) exactness (for long sequences)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say that you missed a step in the definition of the Ext functor. In general, you choose a projective resolution $\ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ and apply the $Hom(-,B)$ functor to the truncated sequence $P_* \rightarrow 0$ (ie, $\ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow 0$. Finally you compute the (co)homology groups.
See the defintion part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor or any notes on the subject.

Comment: I don't know the definition of left exactness for unbounded sequences. My problem is the last step (taking cohomolgy). we want to take cohomolgy of a left exact unbounded sequence so is it zero everywhere except for the last right morphism of the sequence?

Comment: When you truncate the sequence, you still have a complex but the sequence is no longer exact. From the exact sequence $\ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$, you get: $\ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow 0$, which is not exact anymore. You then apply your $Hom$ functor, so you get: $0 \rightarrow Hom(P_0, B) \rightarrow Hom(P_1, B) \rightarrow \ldots$, which is still not exact.
Maybe this may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787767/left-exact-functors-and-long-exact-sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sometimes one calls a **left exact sequence** an exact sequence of the form
  $$\tag{*} 0 \to A' \to A \to A''$$
  and a **right exact sequence** an exact sequence of the form
  $$\tag{**} A' \to A \to A'' \to 0$$
  but this terminology is not very common (I would try to avoid it), and there's no such thing as a left/right exact sequence of arbitrary length, as far as I know.
- A sequence of morphisms
  $$\cdots \to A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}} A_n \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n-1} \to \cdots$$
  is **exact** if $\ker f_n = \operatorname{im} f_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and it is a **complex** if $\operatorname{im} f_{n+1} \subseteq \ker f_n$ for all $n$. Note that an exact sequence is the same thing as a complex with trivial (co)homology.
- The condition $\operatorname{im} f_{n+1} \subseteq \ker f_n$ is equivalent to $f_n\circ f_{n+1} = 0$, and after applying any additive functor $F$ you get
  $$F (f_n)\circ F (f_{n+1}) = F (f_n\circ f_{n+1}) = F (0) = 0,$$
  so that any additive functor maps a complex (in particular, an exact sequence) to a complex. Similarly for contravariant $F$,
  $$F (f_{n+1})\circ F (f_n) = F (f_n\circ f_{n+1}) = F (0) = 0.$$
- If $F$ is exact (i.e. both left and right exact), then it preserves (co)homology:
  $$H_n (F (C_\bullet)) \cong F (H_n (C_\bullet)).$$
  In particular, an exact functor maps an exact sequence of arbitrary length to an exact sequence. If $F$ is contravariant,
  $$H^n (F (C_\bullet)) \cong F (H_n (C_\bullet)).$$
- If $F$ is not exact (not left/right exact), then there is no reason for $F$ to preserve (co)homology of a complex.
- In particular, if you start with a resolution $P_\bullet \twoheadrightarrow A$, then even though the complex
  $$\cdots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to 0$$
  is exact everywhere, except for $P_0$, the corresponding sequence of morphisms
  $$0 \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_0,B) \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_1,B) \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_2,B) \to \cdots$$
  is still a complex, but a priori there is no reason for it to be exact anywhere. Left exactness of $\operatorname{Hom} (-,B)$ will tell you only that the exact sequence
  $$P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0$$
  corresponds to the exact sequence
  $$0 \to \operatorname{Hom} (A,B) \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_0,B) \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_1,B)$$
  that is,

\begin{multline}
H^0 (\operatorname{Hom} (P_\bullet,B)) = \ker (\operatorname{Hom} (P_0,B) \to \operatorname{Hom} (P_1,B)) \cong \\
\operatorname{Hom} (\operatorname{coker} (P_1 \to P_0), B) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (A,B).
\end{multline}

so that $\operatorname{Ext}^0 (A,B) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (A,B)$.

- If $\operatorname{Hom} (-,B)$ is an exact functor (in this case one says that $B$ is **injective**), then it indeed preserves (co)homology, and $\operatorname{Ext}^n (A,B) = 0$ for all $A$ and $n > 0$.
- Here's a minimal example with abelian groups: to calculate $\operatorname{Ext} (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, B)$, we may start with a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$:
  $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times n} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
  After applying $\operatorname{Hom} (-,B)$ to the complex
  $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times n} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
  you get the complex
  $$0 \to B \xrightarrow{\times n} B \to 0$$
  Its cohomology in degree $0$ is
  $$\operatorname{Ext}^0 (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, B) = \ker (B \xrightarrow{\times n} B) = \operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, B),$$
  and its cohomology in degree $1$ is
  $$\operatorname{Ext}^1 (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, B) = \operatorname{coker} (B \xrightarrow{\times n} B) = B/nB,$$
  which is not trivial if the multiplication by $n$ is not surjective on $B$.